# Dynamic label with image in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

We have two(first label dynamic height) labels and one in UITableview and our image size static assume that 120*70

We are setting image **bottom constraint to cell superview** but when Label content height is more than image height, second label going inside cell automatically.

We are using **UITableViewAutomaticDimension**

Here we confused to set constraint to labels, How to proportionally set heights to both labels and image.

If we try to **bottom constraint to label and fixed height to and width to image**, then white space coming at bottom of cell.

My cell design looks like below image:

[image: Cell design Image]

Check my output with below constraints

Output:

[image]

Constraint image:

[image]

Comment: By going inside cell, do you mean that the text is cut? Can you also please explain a little bit more clearly.

Comment: Show what you want with various amounts of text in the labels. If there is more text than the height of the image, how do you want the layout to look? If Top label has multiple lines, and bottom label has only one line? Both labels with only one line? and so on....

Comment: @nasir multiline comes properly, but second label going inside the table

Comment: @DonMag bottom label only one line always, updated question

Comment: @karthikeyan - What I understand is that the top label is multiline and the bottom is a single line. You have a fixed size image. The single-line label should always be aligned to the bottom of the image? If this is the case, then there are a few scenarios:   1. what happens if label 1's text is more than it is possible to be shown in the cell? Does the cell also increase its size? 2. What if both the labels have 1 line of text, does the spacing appear between the labels?

Comment: In this case, Is it right way to set bottom constraint to label? currently we given to image bottom costraint. 1. Yes we wanted to increase it. 2. We should show as it is with image sizes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this easily by setting a bottom constraints of greater-than-or-equal to both the bottom label and the image view.

First, make sure you are using:

```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

so the cells / rows will auto-size to fit the contents.

For the cell prototype, I have (background colors so we can see the frames):

- Multi-Line label constrained Top `8` and Leading `8` (from the superview, not using margins)
- Image View constrained Top `8` and Trailing `0` (from the superview, not using margins), and Width `119` Height `87` (based on your posted image)
- 1-Line Label constrained Leading and Trailing to Multi-Line label, and Top `4` to Multi-Line label
- Multi-Line label is also constrained Trailing `8` to the image view

Now the key is the next two constraints...

- constrain Bottom of 1-Line Label at `>= 8` to Bottom of superview
- constrain Bottom of Image View *also* at `>= 8` to Bottom of superview

[image]

Now, the cell height will auto-expand to fit the taller elements:

[image]

and, how it looks without the colored backgrounds:

[image]

The full project can be found here: https://github.com/DonMag/AnotherExpandingCell

Comment: Thanks a lot man, we appreciate your answer!!! we done it by adding one label below second label and given bottom constraint to that label then we changed its priority from 1000 to 250. now working fine. And your answer good no need of adding extra controls in it.

Comment: If possible share your sample

Comment: @karthikeyan - I added a link at the bottom of my answer to a full project on GitHub

Comment: Is it possible to centre image view label content more? or Do i have to go programmaticllay?

Comment: When label text more than five line, we are seeing white space at image bottom, to fill that we are thinking about centre the imageview to superview

Comment: Add a `center vertically` constraint to the imageView, and then also *change* the `top: 8` constraint to `>= 8` (top of the imageView).

Comment: Then you did something wrong. I updated the code at https://github.com/DonMag/AnotherExpandingCell and it vertically centers the image view as expected.